# Unable to call function as $rootScope is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, web, rootscope

I am trying to call the function inside the controller 'Notification' when getNotification is called in the SelectNotificationCtlr. However when running this I get an Error stating that $rootScope is undefined on the line below console.log("log");. I have tried passing the $rootScope as a parameter in my getNotification function but still receive the same error.

Please see my code below, any advice or help would be really appreciated.

**app.js**

```
selectNotification.controller('selectNotificationCtlr', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'notificationsService',
    function($scope, $http, notificationsService, notificationService, $rootScope) {
        $scope.getNotification = function() {
            var id = $scope.selectedNotification;
            notificationData = notificationsService.getNotifications();
            console.log(notificationData);

            console.log("log");
            $rootScope.$emit("call", {});
        }
    }
]);


selectNotification.controller('Notification', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on("call", function() {
            $scope.parent(notificationService);
        });

        $scope.parent = function() {
            console.log("log");
        }
    }
]);
```

Kind regards

CB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller should have dependencies in the right order,

```
selectNotification.controller('selectNotificationCtlr', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'notificationsService',
    function($scope, $rootScope, notificationsService) {
```

Comment: Yes, works perfectly. Something so simple, yet easily overlooked. Again thank you, morning is 100% better now.